# How to include compodoc files in a Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, compodoc

I am creating app using angular 6 and I would like add the documentation (build with compodoc) in this app but I don't know how add the JS files in the template like in the index.html of compodoc.

I know that I must do some thing like that :

```
var s=document.createElement("script");
s.type="text/javascript";
s.src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/custom-elements"; //external script
```

But in my case the files aren't external but internal and if I put a path like that:

```
 s.src="src/app/documentation/documentation/js/libs/custom-elements.min.js";
```

I have this error:

```
Failed to load for the item <script> whose source is « http://localhost:4200/src/app/documentation/documentation/js/libs/custom-elements.min.js
```

How can i include all these js files in angular app?